# SMTPSenderRefused at /accounts/signup/

Tags: python, django, smtp, gmail

I tried to configure sending email on registration using gmail server and i get these error:
**(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError u2sm3847520edr.70 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost').**
These are my configurations in settings.py

```
 EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
 EMAIL_PORT = 465
 EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
 EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER') 
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

Comment: Did you read the link given?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you configured the environment variables.

```
$ export EMAIL_HOST_USER ="yournotsosecretemail"
$ export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ="yourverysecretpassword"
$ python manage.py runserver
```

I guess that there are other ways to store environment variables, this is just one way. If you want some debugging help, add some `print` statements after the configuration.

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER') 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
print('Email:', EMAIL_HOST_USER)
print('Password:, 'EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to settings.py environment variable:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = env("DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL")
```

where DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER